# How can I reverse an animation after hover like a transition?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

CSS transitions animate back to the previous state, following the transition rules in reverse. But animations don't. They just go back to the original state abruptly (eg., when `:hover` or the class is removed). Is there a way to make animations behave like transitions (like the code below).

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.box.transition {
  background-color: green;
  transition: 500ms linear all;
}

.box.transition:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box.animation {
  background-color: red;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.box.animation:hover {
  animation-name: zoom;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  to {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- If I "unhover" .box.animation, it goes back to the original state abruptly -->
<div class="box transition"></div>
<div class="box animation"></div>
```

Comment: short answer: no ... long anwser: that's why we have transition, if you want he same with animation you need to define too opposite animation

Answer (score 0):

### Animation like transitions

Yes and no you can make them behave similarly but not identical, but not with :hover.

The hover state ends when you stop hovering an element. So when you stop hovering it, the css rule that targets :hover will instantly be removed.

Transition define what to do when there are changes to different states.
Animation go from one state to another defined by an animation.

Setting the animation direction will make it look closer to a transition.

[`animation-direction: alternate;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) will loop over an animation from start to finish and backagain.